# Can donation or charity be a big mistake

Tags: ethics

Suppose I donate my eyes at an eye bank. The eyes are implanted to a rapist who uses it for doing all wrong things with them, then it is not good.

Isn't donating without knowing the recipient a mistake ?

But, knowing your recipient is not possible. So, does that mean donating itself is not right and should be done sparingly ?

Comment: And money can always be used to buy poison, or a gun to shoot someone.  So isn't paying anyone equally problematic?  Or, for that matter, waking up in the morning?  The problem with the Hippocratic heading 'First, do no harm' or the Witches Rede 'An it harm none do an willst' (Do whatever you wish, but only if it harms no one.)  is that absolute harmlessness is absolutely impossible  -- don't breath: because of global warming that will eventualy harm someone.  For consequential logic to work, one has to make some statistical assumptions about human nature.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is broader than just the issue of organ donation. You might do anything that helps someone, or saves their life, and it might happen that they go on to do wicked things. The story goes that when Hitler was a boy he fell into a river and was drowning and a man rescued him. Is the man responsible for the bad things that followed? Clearly not.

Explaining why not will involve different answers depending on your preferred moral theory. A consequentialist might answer that while you are potentially responsible for the actions of others, this can only extend to what is reasonably forseeable. The man who rescued Hitler could hardly be in a position to forsee what would follow. To an absolutist, you are responsible only for your own actions, not those of other people. You may calculate the likely consequences of your actions, but when those consequences involve the will of other people, your moral responsibility does not extend to them. In the Kantian version of deontology, what makes the donation morally right is your motive for doing it, irrespective of the consequences. If you act out of duty to help others, then this is what makes it good.  A proponent of virtue ethics might say that helping people and donating your organs for use after your death is good because it exemplifies the virtue of compassion, and in the absence of any contrary or competing virtue, it is therefore a good thing to do.

Comment: Read a SF story which went like this: Hitler is killed in 1916 during WW1. In 1960, New York is destroyed by a nuclear bomb.

Answer (score 0):

It is irrelevant. When you donate, it is your intention what counts. If it produces a negative impact (negative under your assessment), it is another problem (the solicitor, or part of the chain is lying or mistaken).

But donations have an interesting effect: when you give something for free, you are enforcing a behaviour to repeat. So, if nature would kill people without kidneys for the sake of natural selection, you are not only reverting such behaviour, but enforcing it to change and repeat.

Donations enforce behaviours. Enforcement causes behaviours to repeat.